# rpmbuild gives seg fault

Tags: segmentation-fault, rpmbuild

I am trying to build an rpm using the rpmbuild tool.
I have source code which build binaries around 30 GB. This software for which I am making the rpm has dozens of executables. When I copy only the binaries of a single executable (Eg. init) my rpm builds successfully. But when I dump the entire build to the rpm, rpmbuild does everything but gives a seg fault in the end.

Here is my spec file:

```
# This is a sample spec file for wget

%define _topdir     /root/mywget
%define name            source 
%define release     1
%define version     1.12
%define _builddir     /root/mywget/BUILD/glenlivet
%define _buildrootdir /root/mywget/BUILDROOT
%define _buildroot /root/mywget/BUILDROOT
%define _sourcedir    /root/mywget/SOURCES

BuildRoot:  %{_buildroot}
Summary:        GNU source
License:        GPL
Name:           %{name}
Version:        %{version}
Release:        %{release}
Source:         %{name}-%{version}.tar.gz
Prefix:         /usr
Group:          Development/Tools

%description
The GNU sample program downloads files from the Internet using the command-line.

%prep
%setup -q -n glenlivet

%build
cd %{_builddir}
make all

%install
rm -rf %{_buildrootdir}
mkdir -p %{_buildrootdir}/bin
cp -p -r %{_builddir}/build/obj-x64/* %{_buildrootdir}/bin/

%files
%defattr(-,root,root)
/bin/*
```

If I only copy some of the binaries (let say one utility and its dependent binaries) it works fine.
But when I try to copy the entire build, I get a seg fault.
I get the seg fault after rpmbuild has executed these sections:
%prep
%build
%install

rpmbuild also processes my source file.

Processing files: source-1.12-1

Finding Provides:

Finding Requires:

Finding Supplements:

Provides:......

Requires:......

Checking for unpackaged file(s):/ usr/lib/rpm/check-files /root/mywget/BUILDROOT

Checking for unpackaged file(s):/ usr/lib/rpm/check-files /root/mywget/BUILDROOT

Segmentation fault

Any clue what wrong is going on or where does rpmbuild fails?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I should have google'd more about this issue.
It seems that when trying to create an RPM larger than 2GB rpmbuild has some issues.
There is a bug filed for this:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=433795